# found variable via search not parsed correctly to open function

Tags: python

I have problem that when I try to parse the found filename via glob I cannot use it in many of the functions

```
compare_1 = sorted(glob.iglob('mm_1*'), key=os.path.getctime)[-1]
compare_2 = sorted(glob.iglob('mm_1*'), key=os.path.getctime)[-2]

result = filecmp.cmp(compare_1,compare_2,shallow=False)
```

the compare did not work

```
print(compare_1)
 mm_1687461920.7171414.txt

f=open(compare_1,'r')
    read = f.read()
    print(read)
```

It does not yield any output
but if a directly hardcode the `fileinput` it works fine

```
f=open("mm_1687461920.7171414.txt",'r')
read1 = f.read()
print(read1)
```

**strong text**

```
TradeNB       EventRef      M_BPFOLIO       M_SPFOLIO       M_SENTITY
```

Comment: works fine for me, so you're probably not disclosing all of the issue here.